# Systemd service definition not working

Tags: systemd, python

Defined a systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=WebGPS
After=gpsd.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/daemonize -p /run/gpsd/webgps.pid -o /var/log/webgps.log /usr/bin/python /var/www/gpsd/webgps.py c
TimeoutSec=1200
WorkingDirectory=/run/gpsd
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RuntimeDirectory=gpsd
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/gpsd/webgps.pid
Restart=on-failure
GuessMainPID=true

#User=www-data
#Group=www-data

StateDirectory=gpsd
StateDirectoryMode=0755

PrivateTmp=true
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=false
NoNewPrivileges=true
PrivateDevices=true
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then executed `systemctl daemon-reload`. Allok so far.
Next: `systemctl enable webgps`. Was ok too.
Starting the whole thing with `systemctl start webgps` just does what is expected -- BUT:

```
WorkingDirectory=/run/gpsd
```

This working directory only holds

```
# ll /run/gpsd
insgesamt 4,0K
drwxr-xr-x  2 0 0  60 Feb 27 16:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 25 0 0 880 Feb 27 16:13 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 0 0   5 Feb 27 16:13 webgps.pid
```

Searching for files this started application creates I could find them within `/`! This is not what `WorkingDirectory` lets you assume:

```
# ll /
insgesamt 99K
drwxr-xr-x  21 0 0 4,0K Feb 27 16:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x  21 0 0 4,0K Feb 27 16:13 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 0 0 4,0K Sep  8 06:49 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   3 0 0 2,5K Jan  1  1970 boot/
drwxr-xr-x  16 0 0 3,7K Feb 27 14:35 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 128 0 0  12K Feb 16 06:48 etc/
-rw-r--r--   1 0 0 2,6K Feb 27 16:15 gpsd-c.html
-rw-r--r--   1 0 0 5,3K Feb 27 16:15 gpsd-c.js
drwxr-xr-x   4 0 0 4,0K Apr  8  2019 home/
drwxr-xr-x  16 0 0 4,0K Apr  8  2019 lib/
drwx------   2 0 0  16K Apr  8  2019 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x   3 0 0 4,0K Apr  8  2019 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 0 0 4,0K Apr  8  2019 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   7 0 0 4,0K Apr  8  2019 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 131 0 0    0 Jan  1  1970 proc/
drwx------   7 0 0 4,0K Feb 27 16:11 root/
drwxr-xr-x  25 0 0  880 Feb 27 16:13 run/
drwxr-xr-x   2 0 0 4,0K Sep 11 00:07 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 0 0 4,0K Apr  8  2019 srv/
dr-xr-xr-x  12 0 0    0 Feb 27 16:08 sys/
drwxrwxrwt  11 0 0 4,0K Feb 27 16:15 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  11 0 0 4,0K Apr  8  2019 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  12 0 0 4,0K Aug 20  2019 var/
```

All I could find about states the same: `WorkingDirectory` is the directory the application is run within. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Welcome to the site. For completeness' sake, please edit your post to indicate what OS flavour and version you are using; this kind of information may help to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

"All ok" is not really the description that comes to mind for something that uses the rickety and dangerous PID file mechanism, and the wholly unnecessary `daemonize` program, under a service manager.  Ironically, `daemonize` is the cause of your problem.  It is changing the working directory on you.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /var/www/gpsd/webgps.py c
TimeoutSec=1200
WorkingDirectory=/run/gpsd
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RuntimeDirectory=gpsd
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure

#User=www-data
#Group=www-data

StateDirectory=gpsd
StateDirectoryMode=0755

PrivateTmp=true
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=false
NoNewPrivileges=true
PrivateDevices=true
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true
```

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*You really don't need to daemonize. Really.*](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/daemonize.html).  The systemd House of Horror.